# Pan is not working properly after rotate SVG to 90degree

Tags: svg, rotation, zooming, svg.js, svgpanzoom

```js
var mySVG = SVG('drawing').size(500, 300).attr('id','svg-container').addClass('svg-container');

var panZoomInstance = svgPanZoom('#svg-container', {
 panEnabled: true,
 controlIconsEnabled: false,
 zoomEnabled: true,
 dblClickZoomEnabled: true,
 mouseWheelZoomEnabled: true,
 preventMouseEventsDefault: true,
 zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.2,
 minZoom: 0.5,
 maxZoom: 3,
 fit: false,
 contain: false,
 center: false,
 refreshRate: 'auto',
 
 eventsListenerElement: null 
});
 
(document.getElementById('reset')).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 panZoomInstance.reset();
});
 (document.getElementById('corner')).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 var currentZoom = panZoomInstance.getZoom();
 panZoomInstance.pan({x: -50*currentZoom, y: -120*currentZoom});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.3.6/svg.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="100%" height="100%" id="drawing">
   
    <rect     width="30" height="10" fill="green"/>      

</svg>
 <script>
  
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
var mySVG = SVG('drawing').size(500, 300).attr('id', 'svg-container').addClass('svg-container');

var panZoomInstance = svgPanZoom('#svg-container', {
  panEnabled: true,
  controlIconsEnabled: false,
  zoomEnabled: true,
  dblClickZoomEnabled: true,
  mouseWheelZoomEnabled: true,
  preventMouseEventsDefault: true,
  zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.2,
  minZoom: 0.5,
  maxZoom: 3,
  fit: false,
  contain: false,
  center: false,
  refreshRate: 'auto',

  eventsListenerElement: null
});

(document.getElementById('reset')).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  panZoomInstance.reset();
});
(document.getElementById('corner')).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var currentZoom = panZoomInstance.getZoom();
  panZoomInstance.pan({
    x: -50 * currentZoom,
    y: -120 * currentZoom
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.3.6/svg.js"></script>
<script src="https://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/dist/svg-pan-zoom.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <svg width="100%" height="100%" id="drawing">
    <rect width="80" height="40" fill="green"/>      
</svg>

</body>

</html>
```

When i try to rotate the pan and zoom-able svg to 90 degree, the rotation has happend and zoom also woeking fine as expected. 
But, when i try to pan the rotated svg, it's not working properly as expected. If i click and drag the mouse to left the svg is moving up 
and if i drag to right it's moving down. 
I i click the rotate button, placed transform g tag and apply around svg inner html of the svg.

Comment: Looks like the plugin does not transform your mouse coordinates correctly. You could try svg.panzoom.js which might do that correctly. But jo guarantee! It's also not as feature rich

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have tried that svg.panzoom.js. But not working. I have used svgPanZoom("#id_svg") after rotation.                                   
          jQuery(function () {
                    svgPanZoom('#id_svg', {
                        zoomEnabled: true,
                        controlIconsEnabled: true,
                        fit: true,
                        center: false,
                        minZoom: 0.1
                    });
                });

Comment: I am talking about a different plugin. One which was written for svg.js itself. However as I said: maybe it works for you maybe not